# Please help me to understand how regular expression \\p{So}+" work?

Tags: java

Please help me to understand how regular expression `\\p{So}+` work ?
What will be replaced in below code ?

```
convertedString.replaceAll("\\p{So}+", "");
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It replaces "other symbols" (`\p{So}` is the character class for "other symbols") that are in a sequence of one or more such symbols (`+`). "Other symbols" are "[Various Dingbats, box-drawing symbols, Braille patterns, non-letter Chinese characters, ...](http://www.tzlink.com/tool/Mastering_Regular_Expressions_3rd/0596528124/regex3-CHP-3-SECT-5.html)". So for example,

```
System.out.println("│┥,%".replaceAll("\\p{So}+", "X"));
```

produces `X,%`. Your code appears to be removing all "unusual" symbols.